# How to populate view and table with different values from 2 tables

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i want to edit my view adding some data from 2 different tables which has different data.
My view is the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW LAST_EXEC (
    "FLOW_NAME", "FLOW_TYPE", "DT_CHECKPOINT", "DT_FLOW_START", "DT_FLOW_END", "DURATION", "STATUS", "HOUR_CHECKPOINT", "NUM") 
DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"  AS 
select  
    a.FLOW_NAME, 
    a.FLOW_TYPE, 
    trunc(a.DT_CHECKPOINT) as DT_CHECKPOINT, 
    substr(a.DT_FLOW_START,0,16) as DT_FLOW_START, 
    substr(a.DT_FLOW_END,0,16) as DT_FLOW_END, 
    a.DURATION, 
    a.STATUS, 
    a.HOUR_CHECKPOINT, 
    a.NUM
from report_checkpoint_history a, 
     (select trunc(dt_checkpoint) as trunc_dt_checkpoint,max(time_id) as time_id
      from report_checkpoint_history
      group by trunc(dt_checkpoint)) b 
where trunc(a.dt_checkpoint) = b.trunc_dt_checkpoint and a.time_id = b.time_id
order by trunc(a.dt_checkpoint) asc;
```

In the following query, my view takes FLOW_NAME from table1 but i want that it takes values also from table2 which is different table1.

How can I do?

I expect a new view which takes the values from 2 different tables.
For example:

```
Table 1: has FLOW_NAME: aaa
Table 2: has FLOW_NAME: bbb
```

In this moment my view takes only FLOW_NAME from table1 but I want that on my view, FLOW_NAME is populated having both aaa and bbb.

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do, `FLOW_NAME`  is taken from  `report_checkpoint_history`, from from table1.    Please add some sample data to make clear what the input, and desired output is.

Comment: Are you talking about **UNION** of two queries? One taking data from TABLE1, and another from TABLE2?

Comment: Yes, my view in this moment takes the FLOW_NAME  only from table1 (select a.FLOW_NAME). Now I want that my view takes both FLOW_NAME from table1 and table2